# Changing iOS App Store app from four-segmented version to three

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I know Apple and iTunesConnect are very strict about version numbers always incrementing (which has certainly caused problems for us in the past), so I am naturally hesitant at introducing a four-segment version for a one-off app update with the intent of going back to three segments for the next release.

For example, the current version is `1.0.7`. We need to push an update out for an app that is not on the normal release cadence (minor update, just some graphics changed). Rather than have to bump all future versions, I was thinking to release this patch as `1.0.7.1`, such that the next version can resume at `1.0.8`.

However my worry is that if I introduce a four-segmented version of `1.0.7.1`, Apple won't let me go back to three segments for `1.0.8`.

I obviously can't just try it out to see given that Apple won't let you delete versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem about that. If version number increments, then there won't be any problem.

Let's just base this on real data :) ...

[image]

Notice the change from version 7.0.3 to 7.1.